# Jira Linked Service Error in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, jira, azure-data-factory

I need to pull data from Jira using azure data factory.
When I am using default JIRA connector in Azure data factory I am getting below error.

But I am able to connect via using REST linked service.

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this issue

Comment: Hi @AKHIL KUMAR, is the error solved now?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-jira#linked-service-properties):

Host: The IP address or host name of the Jira service. (for example, jira.example.com).

Just from the document, Please try IP address or the Jira server direclty without 'https://'.